# How can you combine two data frames in r so that the resulting data frame has a new column indicating the data frame of origin?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have two data frames, df1, and df2 and they contain the same column headers so that,

```
df1 = 
price size
10    40
```

and

```
df2 = 
price size
20    50
```

I would to combine these two data frames so that the resulting data frame has,
price size origin

```
10 40 df1
20 50 df2
```

Thoughts?

Comment: first you need to create a third variable with normal assignment in both the data.frames(you assign "df1" and "df2" respectively); then you can use `rbind` to "paste" them.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way as I see it, (if you have many data sets called `df` + some number- though you can choose some other regex pattern too) is to get them all from the global environment and use `do.call/rbind` combination

```
res <- do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+$")))
res
#     price size
# df1    10   40
# df2    20   50
```

If you prefer the origin to be a column instead of row names, you could simply do

```
res$origin <- row.names(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(mget(paste0('df', 1:2)), origin)
#    origin price size
#1   df1    10   40
#2   df2    20   50
```